# Sql query or php array for joining multiple tables and return column as rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, subquery

I have a question about a sql query that will return an array. ( or if it's not possible, maybe there is a way to solve this with an array function in php? )

Here's an example of my database and tables

```
table member
id         name       firstname         active
member1      Doe        John              1
member2      Doe        Jane              1
member3      Doe        Duncan            0
member4      Doe        Marc              1


table member_meeting
member_id      meeting_id      options
1               1              1
1               2              1,2
2               1              2,3,6
2               3              2
4               3              4
4               5              2,3,4

table meeting
    id        start_date    active
meeting1      2018-05-21    1
meeting2      2018-05-21    1
meeting3      2019-05-21    0
meeting4      2020-05-20    1
meeting5      2017-05-20    1
meeting6      2020-05-50    1
```

....

```
What I would like have returned 
            m_1         m_2         m_4       m_6    ...
member1     options     options     NULL     NULL
member2     options     NULL        NULL     NULL 
member4     NULL        NULL        options  NULL
```

So when e member isn't active, it shouldn't be in the end results. When a meeting is already over/ or not active, it also can't be in the end results.  I don't know the amount of members, or meetings. they can change per new meeting request. Can this be returned by sql? or should this be done in php arrays? Another problem, I tried with php, but I ended up with a foreach in a foreach in a foreach. Those are tables with a lot of rows, and I ended up with a very slow loadtime.

Now at the moment I solved it like below. But is there a better way to solve it? I don't like the multiple for each loops. ( And I'm still searching for the same result but with SQL query )

meeting_member is a select query where I add member_id and meeting_id in 1 column 
  so I can use it as keys

```
  $meeting_matrix = array(
    'name' => array(0 => 'neme'),
  );
  foreach ($meetings as $meeting) {
    $meeting_matrix['name'][$meeting->id] = $meeting->title;
  }


  foreach ($members as $member) {
    $options = array();
    $options[] = $member->name . ' ' . $member->firstname;
    foreach ($meetings as $meeting) {
      //start_date
      $options[] = (!empty($meeting_member[$meeting->id . '_' . $member->id]))
        ? $meeting_member[$meeting->id . '_' . $member->id]->option : "";
    }
    $meeting_matrix[$member->name . ' ' . $member->firstname] = $options;
  }
```